# Embedding try-catch blocks within try-catch blocks in Java

Tags: java, exception

Let's say I have method a() and method b() which both may throw an exception. In my program, there is a situation where I have to call at least one of them; it doesn't matter which I call. However, if one of them throws an exception, I have to call the other one. If they both throw an exception, I don't have to do anything.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
try {
    a();
catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        b();
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

but I thought this would be impractical if I had more than two methods to call. So I was wondering if there were a more elegant or better way to do something I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete use case?

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong in the design of your code. This is not the way one typically uses exceptions.

Comment: I apologize, I can't be more specific about it because it relates to a school project. Thank you for the help though! Ignis, I think you are probably right; I think I am thinking about doing the problem in the wrong way, and I will try to figure it all out another way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can

```
    abc:
    {
        try
        {
            a();
            break abc;
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        try
        {
            b();
            break abc;
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        try
        {
            c();
            break abc;
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

---

if the chain is even longer, probably better

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    try 
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: a(); break;
            case 1: b(); break;
            case 2: c(); break;
            case 3: d(); break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){} // next
}
```

Comment: +1 because I've not seen this before. Worth considering as an option.

Comment: This looks eerily similar to a goto.

Comment: @NullUserException more like a return

Answer (score 2):

You can return after each case, such that after the first success, a return is hit.

```
public void uponSuccessStop() {
    try {
        a();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        b();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        c();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Another option would be to throw out exceptions, and use short-circuit boolean logic:

```
public boolean tryA() {
    try {
        a();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
// repeat for B and C

public void uponSuccessStop() {
    boolean succeeded = tryA() || tryB() || tryC();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to discuss practical options at such a level of generality, but you could do something like this:

```
boolean succeeded = false;
try {
    a();
    succeeded = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // intentional ...
}
if (not succeeded) {
    try {
        b();
    catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

... and all sort of other arrangements where you use conditionals (or `break` or `return`) to avoid the nesting.

But whether they are more "elegant" ... or more readable ... will be highly context dependent.  And also dependent on the reader.  (As an experienced Java programmer, I have no difficulty understanding nested exceptions.  In my experience, artificial constructions that are *intended* to avoid nesting can result in code that is *harder* to read / understand.)

---

I hope that you are not *really* going to catch `Exception` ... 'cos if you are, that is a *much* worse problem than than nesting of try / catch!!